# Problem using two TB Mega Menus one above the other

Tags: 7, javascript, theming, navigation

I am using Drupal 7 with the [TB Mega Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu) module. I have one menu positioned below the other in the following configuration:

```
__________________________________________
|  Menu bar 1                            |
------------------------------------------
|  Menu bar 2                            |
------------------------------------------
```

Both Menu bar 1 and Menu bar 2 have drop down menus. The problem is that when Menu bar 1's drop down menu is being displayed, it is showing up behind Menu bar 2. I thought this was a z-ordering problem and tried changed the values for both menus but it doesn't change the outcome.

I looked at the javascipt code for TB Mega Menus and don't see anything in there about z-ordering either.

There must be something I am missing/overlooking. Any ideas as to what I should be looking for in order to get this to work?

Comment: When you tried changing z-index did you make sure both divs were positioned?

Comment: I made both of its containing div position: relative. No change in behaviour.